# Помогите определить правильную кодировку в англоязычной Windows

Tags: delphi, windows, кодировка, delphi-7, firebird

Delphi7, FireBird2.5, Windows 10 (Англ. версия)

В БД (программа), русский шрифт отображается нормально.
В MS Word, при Windows 10 (Рус. версия), русский шрифт выводится нормально.
Если используется английская версия Windows, то выводится, абракодабра, типа (рис. в низу):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В конце перепробывл функции: AnsiToUtf8, UnicodeToUtf8, UTF8Encode, Utf8ToAnsi, Utf8ToUnicode (при выводе в MSWord) – не подходит
Делал вот так:

```
...
s := UTF8Encode(WideString(ibqEmpty.FieldByName('RusWord').AsString));     
WordApplication1.Selection.TypeText(ibqEmpty.FieldByName('EngWord').AsString + ' - ' + Copy(ibqEmpty.FieldByName('RusWord').AsString, 0, 1) + LSpace_empty_FO1C +' - ' + s);
```

При сохранении этого документа (rtf) в txt (в MSWord можно подбирать кодировку), ни одна не подошла
А на самой форме, вместо киррилицы, стоят "?????" (но тут уже от языка системы не зависит)

Спасибо

Comment: используйте кодировку UTF для самой базы и для вывода информации.

Comment: Я делал так:    

s := UTF8Encode(WideString(ibqEmpty.FieldByName('RW1').AsString));
WordApplication1.Selection.TypeText(ibqEmpty.FieldByName('EngWord').AsString + '               - '  + Copy(ibqEmpty.FieldByName('RW1').AsString, 0, 1) + LSpace_empty_FO1C +' - '
 + s);  - ***но это не работает*, т.е. КОДИРОВКА МЕНЯЕТСЯ, НО НЕ НА ТУ

Comment: Непонятно, где именно у вас проблемы. Только с отображением на форме, раз "в БД все нормально, в MSWord нормально"?

Answer (score 2):

Обычно такая проблема возникает, когда у Вас не-Unicode приложение и неправильно установлены региональные настройки в Windows. Выставите правильные настройки через "Панель управления" и скорее всего все работает. Повторюсь - если не хотите иметь проблем ВООБЩЕ - пишите сразу под Unicode. Благо никаких причин писать не в Unicode уже не осталось.

Описание алгоритма как поправить ситуацию:
https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/int_pr_select_language_version.mspx?mfr=true

> 1. Open Regional and Language Options in Control Panel.
> 2. On the Advanced tab, under Language for non-Unicode programs, click the language version of non-Unicode programs that will be used.

Иногда это не помогает.
Тогда рекомендуют сделать так:

> Запустите редактор реестра (Пуск — Выполнить -> regedit).
>
> При выполнении следующих действий будьте предельно внимательны —
>   неосторожная работа с реестром Windows может привести к печальным
>   последствиям!
>
> Необходимо поменять значения параметров с «1250» по «1255» —
>   установить значение для каждого из этих параметров «c_1251.nls» — в
>   следующих ключах:
>
> Код:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Nls\CodePage
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet002\Control\Nls\CodePage
>
> Необходима перезагрузка.
>
> Исправление кодировки в Windows XP
>
> Чтобы ручками не лазить в реестре Windows, попробуйте сделать
>   следующее:
>
> Создать файл в блокноте, скопировав в него приведенный ниже текст,
>   сохранить с расширением «reg» с любым названием, английскими буквами,
>   например 1251.reg, и запустить его. В 90% случаев с «кракозябрами» XP
>   помогает.
>
> Код:
>
> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage]
>   «1250»=»c_1251.nls»
>   «1251»=»c_1251.nls»
>   «1252»=»c_1251.nls»
>   «1253»=»c_1251.nls»
>   «1254»=»c_1251.nls»
>   «1255»=»c_1251.nls»
>
> Либо подправить в ветке реестра, отвечающей за отображение шрифтов
>   кириллицы.
>
> Код:
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage]
>
> изменив на следующие параметры:
>
> Код:
>
> 1251 REG_SZ c_1251.nls
>   1252 REG_SZ c_1251.nls
>   1253 REG_SZ c_1251.nls
>
> Если не помогает, то дополнительно изменить:
>
> Код:
>
> 1254 REG_SZ c_1251.nls
>   1255 REG_SZ c_1251.nls

Comment: 1) Да региональные настройки, может быть не очень верны, в том смысле что, я нахожусь в Украине, а общий язык в системе выставил - английский (мне так необходимо).
2) Замена значений в реестре на "c_1251.nls" - тоже не помогло
3) Используя http://www.tenforums.com/general-support/20884-how-do-you-change-language-settings-non-unicode-programs-win10.html , у меня стоит "Ukraine"

Comment: "Необходимо поменять значения параметров с «1250» по «1255» — установить значение для каждого из этих параметров «c_1251.nls» — в следующих ключах:" - никогда, никогда, никогда не делайте так! Потому что после этого очень часто начинает глючить кодировка в **правильно** написанных приложениях, а найти причину бывает очень сложно.

Comment: @Konstantin78, 1) - это не язык системы, а кодовая страница по-умолчанию для не-unicode приложений. Т.е. то, как будут интерпретироваться Ansi-строки. На язык надписей в системе это никак не влияет.

Comment: Что самое противное, то это то что в Windows 8.1 - все замечательно работало.   - С "изменением c_1251.nls" - наверно пронесло... Пока ничего не испортилось :)

Comment: @Alekcvp Хочу сказать две вещи. Первая - второй алгоритм ( с правкой реестра ) уже для ситуации, когда все средства безнадежны. Второе - этот метод почему-то считается классическим для лечения локализованной версии продуктов Adobe (он повторяется от сайта к сайту) и действительно регулярно помогает. Хотя шансы упороть систему окончательно есть всегда.

Comment: @kami. Основная проблема при выводе в MSOffice. В самой БД, поле с киррилицей, у меня под win1251. Может использовать Unicode? Тогда вопрос как его использовать? хотя в MSOffice, тоже наверно win1251

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я помню, в Delphi 7 тип `string` не юникодовый. Кодировка портится еще при вызове FieldByName('RusWord').AsString.
Не помню, есть ли в 7 версии метод AsWideString. Если есть, то нужно использовать его.

Comment: @ Герман Борисов, если так (var
  s: WideString;
........
s :=
  ibqEmpty.FieldByName('EngWord').AsString + ' - ' + 
  Copy(ibqEmpty.FieldByName('RusWord').AsString, 0, 1) + 
  LSpace_empty_FO1C + ' - ' + 
  ibqEmpty.FieldByName('RusWord').AsString;     
WordApplication1.Selection.TypeText(s);  **Выходит тоже самое** толко крокозябры другие, да и при этом они появляются в *Watches* (при пошаговой трассировке)

Comment: @Konstantin78, попробуйте в последнем примере все .AsString заменить на .AsWideString

Answer (score 1):

Как на другом форуме посоветовали: "**кодирования в юникод не из GetACP, а из 1251**" - это РАБОТАЕТ

```
var
  s: AnsiString;
  ws: WideString;
  len: Integer;
........
s := ibqEmpty.FieldByName('EngWord').AsString + ' - ' +  Copy(ibqEmpty.FieldByName('RusWord').AsString, 0, 1) + LSpace_empty_FO1C + ' - ' + ibqEmpty.FieldByName('RusWord').AsString;
len := Length(s);
SetLength(ws, len);
len := MultiByteToWideChar(1251, 0, PAnsiChar(s), len, PWideChar(ws), len);
if len = 0 then
  RaiseLastOSError;
SetLength(ws, len);
WordApplication1.Selection.TypeText(ws);
```

Comment: Это значит, что данные в базе не в Unicode. Правильное решение — поменять кодировку данных в базе на Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

мне помогло regedit см по ссылке

https://remontka.pro/fix-cyrillic-windows-10/

delphi в редакторе контекст-меню>file format> utf8